# Why does protractor fails if ng-app is in the same tag as ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have an issue that when **ng-app is on the same tag as** (AngularUI) **ui-view**, none of my tests run and I get:

`Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {"message":"angular.element(...).injector(...) is undefined","stackTrace":[{"fileName":"http://localhost:3000/","lineNumber":71,"methodName":"anonymous/<"},{"fileName":"http://localhost:3000/","lineNumber":76,"methodName":"anonymous"},{"fileName":"http://localhost:3000/","lineNumber":68,"methodName":"handleEvaluateEvent"}]}`

Html that gives me the above error:

`<html><head></head><body>
  <div ng-app="app" ui-view></div>
</body></html>`

If I move the **ui-view directive to a nested div**, my tests work fine:

`<html><head></head><body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</body></html>`

My app works fine with either tag configuration, only the tests have errors with the first one.

What could be the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: I could give you 10000 +1 for pointing me to the fact that I've also set ng-app and ng-ui-view to the same <body>-tag and wasted 2 hours to find out that this is letting my protractor tests fail with "Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page". Quick solution: put another div inside the index.html (waste some extra space for that but ist works...). Maybe you could start a issue on github for protractor?

Comment: @Sebastian I've just created an issue on protractor: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1147. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when ng-app and ui-view are declared on the same element, angular.element().injector() is undefined. However, if they're on different elements, the injector exists for both elements.

This is because of an interaction between ui-router and angular, because the ui-view directive uses transclusion. Using a directive using transclusion on the same element as ng-app results in it not having the correct injector via angular.element().injector(). Here's a simplified example: https://gist.github.com/juliemr/ffccf5bbe5b88a2d3da9

I think that this is all working as intended and the solution is to just not use ng-app and ui-view on the same element.

Comment: Do you know why window.angular.element('*:not([ui-view])[ng-app]').injector() still returns undefined error?